# Autocomplet extender control in ajax (asp.net)?

Tags: asp.net

I am using autocomplete extender in my application but it is not working. This is my code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:scriptmanager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<div>
    <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender TargetControlID="TextBox1" MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
    ServiceMethod="GetVideoTitles" CompletionSetCount="10" ServicePath="Myservices.asmx" ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server">
    </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
</div>
</form>
```

This is the webservice method:

```
public string[] GetVideoTitles(string prefixText)
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SERVER5\SQLserver2005;Initial Catalog=tpvnew;User ID=xx;Password=525");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("video_videotitles", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@prefixText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    cmd.Parameters["@prefixText"].Value = prefixText;

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
    da.Fill(dt);
    string[] items = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        items.SetValue(dr["videotitle"].ToString(), i);
        i++;
    }
    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting a breakpoint in your GetVideoTitles method, and verified that it returns any items?

Comment: break point is not firing. when  i make a startuppage as a webservice(Myservices.mscx) it is working fine. but when i make startuppage as a default.aspx it is not showing any dropdown for my texbox

Comment: I assume that the servicepath is correct and that you can access it directly: Maybe you lack the attributes [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod] on the method, and [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] on the webservice class?

Comment: You also need the WebMethod attribute. Did you try to access the webservice directly (http://yoururl/Myservices.asmx)?

Comment: ya i tried it is working fine i think problem in    asp.net page

Answer (score 1):

Try this trick

```
public string[] GetVideoTitles(string prefixText) {
    try 
    {
    ...Your code...

          foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
          {
             items.SetValue(dr["videotitle"].ToString(), i);
             Debug.Write(dr["videotitle"].ToString());  
             i++;
          }
     ...Your code...
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
       Debug.Assert(false);
    }
}
```

This way you first locate if somthing stop running on webservice method.
Also use the DebugView from sysinternals to check live the data you get from Debug.write()

[Debug View](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx)

Hope this 2 thinks help you locate the bug.

-- Found this on asp.net forums--
http://forums.asp.net/t/1123944.aspx

In most cases where the WebService method does not get calls becasue the WebMethod Signature does not match with the AutoComplete Extender signature. The Method signature needs to be:

**string[] WSMethodName(string prefixText, int count)**

You can have different method name but the parameter names and return type needs to be exact match even in case.

Reading this page
http://www.vishwamohan.com/post/2007/05/07/AJAX-Error-Sys-is-undefined.aspx

and this page
http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/TAxworthy/archive/2009/01/15/569.aspx
Found that the sys problem can solve that way....

The most important line was:

**allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"**

```
<section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"   requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
```

When compared to the application’s web.config, the last section was missing. When this line was amended, the javascript error was fixed, and the AJAX controls worked correctly again.

Comment: Mr. Aristos it is giving erro like this 
'Myservices.GetVideoTitles(string)': not all code paths return a value




public string[] GetVideoTitles(string prefixText)
      {
          try

Comment: ya Mr. Aristos i slove the error, but autocompletion is not working

Comment: Do you run the DebugView to see if you get results from Debug.write ? If you not get, then you never call them... or maybe you call them with wronge attribute, then maybe you place a debug.write on the start of the page to see 1) if its called, then if its called and get data, you can search why not show, or else if never called you must see why not fire...

Comment: ya i run the debuview to see  the results ya i am getting but it is not reflecting at default.aspx page.

Comment: i think it is not returning when foreach is completed the return item not showing anything in a debug view

Comment: You are in good road... you see nothing in debug view, so the Myservices.asmx is not called - or not data found... Place one more Debug.write, on the start of the function, to see if its called and with what arguments, then if you see that is not called, probably not found on disk ??? or there is a javascript error ???

Comment: Hey I think I found it. I type it on the replay - check it

Comment: You see that you function is missing an int ! on arguments.

Comment: ya but it is still giving same problem

Comment: The next think, is to run it with ie, and have open all javascript error pop up to locate a possible javascript error

Comment: ya i am getting javascript erro like  'sys' is undefined

Comment: I type more comments on the question, please see them - for the sys is underfined

Comment: Ya javascript error is not displaying but autocomplete is not working when i type 'b' the related 'titles' r not displaying

Comment: Can you check the debug view whats happend ? did program pass from there ? did find results ? Maybe play with the MinimumPrefixLength="1", make it 0 to see whats happeds.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if your web method GetVideoTitles() works or not.
if it works, then check if you have set your .asmx web service path in the scriptmanager.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smMain" runat="server">
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference  Path="~/WebServices/AutoComplete.asmx"/>
        </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebService.asmx" />
            </Services>

Comment: can you put 
CompletionInterval="1000"
EnableCaching="true" to the extender to see if it helps? Try to map your extender setting with the microsoft sample: 
http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

it works for me. 

Also, if your web method returns data in the response then it probably is your autocomplete extender setting issue. Try to check if you are missing any property.

Answer (score 0):

you miss this

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@prefixText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = **prefixText + "%"**;
```

and in your query must use

```
like @prefixText
```